# make multiple <span> auto break line in a container

Tags: javascript, css, inline

My question is as shown from here: [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/oubgpy8m/1/)

As you can see, the `<span>` element will automatically break line if I put each `<span>` on a new line in the `html` file.

But, if I put them one by one together, they will not break line.

Please Note, why I asked this question is because in my real project, I added the `<span>` from my `js` code dynamically.  That will cause the same problem, which is that the `<span>` can't automatically break line, and will add a horizontal scrollbar when the number of them increased.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

*p.s.  I'm using Jquery and Bootstrap 3 in my code.*

Comment: .well span { display:inline-block;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ryad/4tauch8k/) 
Since No body mentioned it I'm going to add this:
If you just append `&nbsp;` a html space entity or a even a normal space `' '` everything will work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $well = $('<div class="well"/>');
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){

        var $span = $('<span class="label label-warning"/>');
        $span.html("hello world!");
        $well.append($span);
        //this will work but will add an additional space $well.append(' &nbsp; ');
        $well.append(' ');
    }
    $('body').append($well);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make your span tags acts like `inline-block` elements. They will display `inline` but if they does not fit on the container they will go to the next line.

```
span{
   display: inline-block !important;
}
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oubgpy8m/17/)**.

Comment: @Ryad.iv I think now is what he needs. Before I have misunderstood his question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to apply an `inline-block` to the spans within the targeted `div`.  You'll want to declare the specificity though to ensure that it only targets the spans within the `.well` container. Else, all of the `spans` with that class attribute will be affected on the web page.

In your CSS, add the following:

```
.well span.label {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

- You do not need to force it with an `!important`.
- While you can specify a maximum width, why would you?  Just let the text determine the width.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hellofromtonya/oubgpy8m/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `display:inline-block` and set `max-width` to your span.

https://jsfiddle.net/oubgpy8m/16/

```
.label{
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 120px;
  margin:5px;
}
```